# IAM/ACL policy to permit per-user Google Cloud Storage object ownership

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket, and I have the following use-case:

- User A needs to be able to create objects, and be able to delete those objects and *only* those objects.
- User B needs to be able to create objects, and be able to delete those objects and *only* those objects.

Is this possible to permit and enforce with IAM and/or ACLs?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The [`storage.objects.delete`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#object_permissions) permission needed to delete objects within a GCS bucket, allows deletion of any object, no matter whether the object is owned through the ACL by the user attempting the deletion or not.

The workaround I can see, is to separately give User A and User B access to two different GCS buckets, by giving each User the required permissions to create/delete objects in them, or by giving them the role [`roles/storage.objectAdmin`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles), i.e:

- Give User A the role `roles/storage.objectAdmin` to Bucket A in the
  bucket permissions tab.
- Give User B the role `roles/storage.objectAdmin` to Bucket B in the bucket permissions tab.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions#bucket-add)'s an example on how to do it.